# What's the difference between fourth and fifth normal form?

Tags: database

They seem similar to me, especially when it comes to decomposition. What exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relation R is in 4NF iff every nontrivial join dependency, J, satisfied by R is implied by the candidate keys of R, where J consists of a join dependency on any **2** projections of R (R1,R2).

A relation R is in 5NF iff every nontrivial join dependency, J, satisfied by R is implied by the candidate keys of R, where J consists of a join dependency on any **n** projections of R (R1,R2, ... Rn).

In other words 4NF is very like 5NF but only 2-part join dependencies are relevant under 4NF whereas all N-part join dependencies must be considered in order to meet the conditions of 5NF. 4NF is therefore not very important and exists for historical reasons only, i.e. because it happened to be discovered and published first. In practical terms it's probably easier to ignore 4NF because 5NF is much more useful and important.

Answer (score 0):

An entity is in Fourth Normal Form (4NF) when it meets the requirement of being in Third Normal Form (3NF) and additionally:
Has no multiple sets of multi-valued dependencies. In other words, 4NF states that no entity can have more than a single one-to-many relationship within an entity if the one-to-many attributes are independent of each other.
Many:many relationships are resolved independently.
Fifth Normal Form   An entity is in Fifth Normal Form (5NF) if, and only if, it is in 4NF and every join dependency for the entity is a consequence of its candidate keys.
Visit this link for detailed description
http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm

Answer (score 0):

If we can decompose table further to eliminate redundancy and anomaly, and when we re-join the decomposed tables by means of candidate keys, we should not be losing the original data or any new record set should not arise. In simple words, joining two or more decomposed table should not lose records nor create new records.

where as in 4nf no records are lost or new records are created.

Answer (score -1):

It has to meet the fourth normal form
Additional the entity consists of a key attribute and a non-key attribute only